# Redux state dont att when I fetch something from an API

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

So, I made an API to store some data, and the redux dont att the state. The fetch is correct, and I reshaped the fetch to store in the state and use on my app.

My reducer:

```
case "FETCH_SUCESS":
      //state.servicos = {...Object.values(action.payload)}
      let ap = action.payload
      ap.map((item,index) => {
        state.servicos[index] = item
      })

      return {
        ...state,
        ...state.servicos
      }
```

my MapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    cadastro: state.cadastro.servicos
  }
  };
```

my Action

```
  export function fetchSucess(resp) {
    resp = shapeData(resp)
  return {
    type: "FETCH_SUCESS",
    payload: resp
  }
}
```

my reshape Function

```
export function shapeData(resp){
//console.log(resp);
//console.log(Object.keys(resp.data))
let dataArray = new Array();
Object.values(resp.data).forEach(item => {
  let reshapeData={
    _id: item.ordem.id,
    teste: teste,

  };
  dataArray.unshift(reshapeData);
})
return dataArray;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to store a servicos key in your state. Also, I do not see the `shapeData` function being called anywhere

Comment: In your reducer, `ap.map` returns a new array. It doesn't alter the original array.

Comment: Sorry, forget to put where i call the reshapeData

Answer (score 0):

This code mutates the old state but does not generate a new one (therefore react-redux has no mean to know that the data changed and re-render). You should instead create a new array for your `servicos` state like this :

```
case "FETCH_SUCESS":
  //state.servicos = {...Object.values(action.payload)}
  let ap = action.payload


  return {
    ...state,
    servicos: [...ap]
  }
```

Comment: then i just delete the servicos object in the INITIAL_STATE?

Comment: What do you mean delete the array from the INITIAL_STATE ? I don't really know your application but it would make sense to provide an empty array as servicos in the INITIAL_STATE